# Get Windows user account SID by account name only

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-security, windows-users

I am trying to programmatically delete a user profile (the right way) using the [DeleteProfile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762273(v=vs.85).aspx) API. Unfortunately, it wants an account SID as the first parameter.

There has to be some magical API that takes a username and spits out an SID, correct? I can't seem to find anything online that is uses native code (I am not using .NET managed code and don't want to use WMI queries or powershell or cmdline tools, etc)

I know you can use the Net32Api to delete an account, but that still leaves artifacts like profile directory, etc. I just want a way to cleanly delete a profile (obviously from elevated code).

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `LookupAccountName()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ha... looks like that's the "magical API" I was talking about. I'll go try it out. Thanks, buddy.

Comment: @Frankie_C -- Yeah that works... Thanks. I was losing my mind. If you answer with that, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the buddy function `LookupAccountName()`.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159(v=vs.85).aspx